# Smooth vectors form a dense subset

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Let $V$ be a continuous representation of a totally disconnected group $G$. Let me recall that vector $v \in V$ is called *smooth* if the corresponding stabilizer is an open subgroup. (In fact, it is known that is always the case if $\operatorname{dim}(V) < \infty$.)

Bernstein in his Harvard notes claims that the smooth vectors of a given $V$ form a dense subset in $V$.

How to prove this fact?

Comment: This is nothing depending on Harvard notes. I suppose you mean the notes [here](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/), from the Tel Aviv Homepage.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, it is the same Bernstein! But I've mentioned Harvard because I'm dealing with [this](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/Jerusalem_2010/GradStudentSeminar/p-adic.pdf) notes of a course given in Harvard. 

I should add the link into my post...

Thank you!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you! The link you've given is slightly irrelevant, i.e. they're talking about the Lie group action on Hilbert space... Maybe you will be so kind to give me a link to the relevant book on representation theory of p-adic groups? I've tried to find it by myself for some time and didn't succeed at all... I'm sorry!

Comment: Yes, here we have an $\ell$-group  and $V$ is a topological representation. But this should go similarly. I found even a possible duplicate on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55600/if-f-v-is-a-nonzero-representation-of-the-reductive-group-gl-n-mathbb-q-p). It says " in a representation of a totally disconnected topological group on a locally convex, quasi-complete (complex) topological vector space, smooth vectors are dense." I will look for more references.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, it seems that both of the answers to this question contain just a formulation the desired result, not its proof...

The details of the "similarity" you've mentioned are also slightly unclear for me...

Very sorry for my silliness!